# Movies self-evaluation: let's get critical!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, quality-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

---

**Feedback from the Stack Exchange Lair**

We are pretty pleased with the changes from last evaluation to this one.

We agree with the community's take on each question here. Your traffic has also been improving. What you're lacking a bit in now is users and new content.

Our recommendation from this point is to keep doing what you're doing:

- sustain the traffic
- continue to steer clear from basic trivia type questions as much as possible
- provide in-depth, well-researched answers.

You are on the right track at the moment.

Answer (score 8):

[How did they get to Singapore in Pirates of the Caribbean At World's End?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2612/how-did-they-get-to-singapore-in-pirates-of-the-caribbean-at-worlds-end)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: A somewhat curious question about the time-span of a movie that's not inherently noticable to the casual viewer, but it is a compelling question on how it would be done.

Comment: Which at first seems a bit odd is actually a pretty interresting plot-explanation question about something not everybody would notice or think about.

Comment: The question seems to be one of those nagging questions a viewer sometimes has and the answer uses sound science to explain. I think they both would help to attract a user to this site.

Comment: The same way they got to China so quickly in 2012 - movie geography. It is an interesting question though.

Answer (score 6):

[Was Frodo Baggins in the original version of The Hobbit?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2633/was-frodo-baggins-in-the-original-version-of-the-hobbit)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Another interesting question with a good answer.  The only thing I can say is that this is comparing a forthcoming movie that is a book adaptation, and might belong a little bit more on sci-fi than here.

Comment: One of the better movie-vs-book examples with a good answer.

Comment: A good question that actually fixed my own memory, for some reason I thought I remembered Frodo mentioned at the end of the Hobbit. In opposition to DForck42 though I think this is a perfect question for this site because it is about the movie coming out compared to the source material, even if the movie isn't out yet it is known that Elijah Wood will be making a cameo as Frodo. I also like that the answer did not source wiki which is to often the only source given.

Comment: I'm biased, but I think this is the perfect kind of Q & A for this site :)

Answer (score 6):

[How do they film minors smoking?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/how-do-they-film-minors-smoking)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This question is about something that we can see in numerous movies that we may never have really thought about.  The answers are informative and interesting to me.  Another good question.

Comment: I for myself am not that much into filming techniques in contrast to content, but I also think this is a valid question with good answers, even if not a signboard for the site.

Comment: What I really like about this question is the tag is dead-on with the question. This is the kind of question that can spark an interest into the actual process of making movie. Christian Rau is correct it's not a question that will draw people to the site but it is the type that may interest them in staying.

Answer (score 5):

[In "Synecdoche, New York" what is the meaning of the character name Sammy Barnathan?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2571/in-synecdoche-new-york-what-is-the-meaning-of-the-character-name-sammy-barnat)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Ahh, this is a good question.  The asker is looking for the answer to what the hidden meaning of a character's name may be, especially since it was hinted at by the director of the movie.  The answer is adequate.

Comment: Though I don't know the movie, it seems like a very good question about the deeper meaning of a character name. And it also got a good answer, even if this answer seems like a 99% correct one (for an outsider at least) that didn't yet get accepted. Maybe not good practice but definitely a good question-answer pair.

Comment: It's good question mainly because Charlie Kaufman hinted that the name meant something. The answer is great as it comes directly from a book about the author and mentions the exact meaning behind the name.

Answer (score 4):

[Am I only missing nudity and violence?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2603/am-i-only-missing-nudity-and-violence)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This is actually a somewhat interesting question becasue it combines censorship with the advancement of the plot in the show.

Comment: Although at first it seems to be about a particular airing of the show, it's a valid question about the importance of censored scenes for the actual plot.

Comment: What bothers me about this question is that the answer can only be speculation. A really great answer would compare sprecific scenes by having a video or several screencaps. But for this the answerer would need to have both versions of the series.

Comment: This is a question that intrigues me. I honestly haven't thought about how much plot or character development could actually be missed by cutting out the sex and violence in this series. It also expands my worldview. I don't think that you do need both the uncut and cut version to compare if it was about actual edits or blurring then yes it would matter. but in this instance you can simply remove a scene that shows nudity or violence and determine if it would affect anything. Overall good question good answer (once again with a good source).

Comment: I think this is a terrific question as it really confronts the nature of censorship and whether or not it adversely affects the director's intentions.

Answer (score 3):

[Boy carves Initials onto turtle shell; years later, turtle is gigantic](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2533/boy-carves-initials-onto-turtle-shell-years-later-turtle-is-gigantic)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: ID question.  Question is written pretty clearly.  It has a moderatley upvoted answer that has been accepted.  However, the accepted answer doesn't have a synopsis of the movie and instead is just a link.  Barring th elack of information, I think this is a good question.

Comment: Whereas I for myself have nothing against ID questions, I at least don't up-vote them as I'm not completely decided about their actual long-time value.

Comment: It's a basic ID question (which seems to be a love it or hate it question topic) This one I would put at mid range the asker seems somewhat vague and mentions a real-life event which confuses the question some also they didn't add many details about their movie (which sometimes there aren't a lot remembered) also the answer does post a good guess and a link. While I don't think that a plot needs to be in the answer since it is easily found on the link I do think that adding what similarities there are between the two. ID questions can bring someone to the site as well as interesting questions

Answer (score 2):

[What is the name of the (non-English language) movie which is mostly set in a school](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2589/what-the-name-of-the-non-english-language-movie-which-is-mostly-set-in-a-schoo)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Another id question, and not overly compelling. Adequate information was given and a mostly adequate answer was given.  Not one of our best, but not one of our worst.

Comment: Like said, I won't up-vote ID questions even if I have nothing against them (and answered this one). They shouldn't be the signboard of our site.

Comment: I like ID questions. This is a good one for two reasons. One the writer put in specific details about when and where they saw it which helps a lot in identifying the correct movie. Second the comments really help to direct the writer so that his question can be answered correctly. Also the Answer is good and helps to point out similarities and has a link. These are the questions that can bring an individual in to the site to ask but the way they are answered and responded to can help make them a regular.

Answer (score -2):

[How are movies chosen for the MTV Movie Awards?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2661/how-are-movies-chosen-for-the-mtv-movie-awards)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Meh, again a question rather about the movie industry that the movies itself, but I guess it's at least on-topic.

Comment: I think this is a question that unfortunately looks like something you would find on a test. It seems like a basic answer (like the one provided) is all that is needed and there not really a lot about it that intrigues me. I do like that DForck42 did a follow up comment on the answer asking for the missing information that is keeping him from accepting it though.

Comment: I asked this question to expand on our footprint for different movie awards.  I genuinely looked up to see if I could find this answer, but wasn't presented with much.  The answer I was provided wasn't anything spectacular, and didn't go into any sort of detail.

Answer (score -2):

[What is the name of old lego racing animated series?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2630/what-is-the-name-of-old-lego-racing-animated-series)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: A somewhat interesting ID question with a somewhat lacking answer.

Comment: It's a decent question. It gives all of the details it can.  The accepted answer though I don't really like because even though they give the information for what they've found it seems a bit like throwing darts at a board and after viewing the links I'm still not sure if the question was actually answered. Either the reasons for it being the correct answer should be stated in the answer or in a comment underneath.

Answer (score -5):

[Why does Madhavan help his ex-wife in the first place?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2522/why-does-madhavan-help-his-ex-wife-in-the-first-place)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: A self-answer question that, without more information in the initial question, is somewhat uncompelling and disinteresting, especially if one is unfamilier with the movie.

Comment: Self-answers can be a good idea, but as this seems like the question is very simple and answers itself pretty obviously throughout the movie, this is probably not that good an example.

Comment: There is no future to this answer and i think the self answered question which is not helpful for future visitor shouldn't welcomed here